# 2 request by 1 MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wanna select from 2 tables.

In first table I want select all data.

In second table I want select only "name".

'edition' in first table it's 'id' in second table.

I wrote sql code, but it isn't work:

```
SELECT link, title, description, imgUri, vkCount, fbCount, twCount, edition
FROM articles
RIGHT JOIN SELECT name
FROM editions
WHERE id = articles.edition
ORDER BY (vkCount + fbCount + twCount) DESC
LIMIT 0, $count
```

Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTZfj.png

Comment: please post your table structure.

Comment: Please take a SQL tutorial. This is a very basic SQL question and your syntax is completely wrong.

Comment: @Thorsten http://i.imgur.com/bMcokCp.png

Comment: This is the definitive answer to the question "how many dollar signs does it take to tag a post as php? "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks pretty close but you have the **JOIN** syntax a little wrong. Use **ON** for a join and only one SELECT clause

```
SELECT link, title, description, imgUri, vkCount, fbCount, twCount, edition, name
  FROM articles
  JOIN editions ON id = articles.edition
ORDER BY (vkCount + fbCount + twCount) DESC
LIMIT 0, $count
```